# Como criar um Protocolo de URL

Tags: java, windows, url

Bom, eu gostaria de saber como posso criar um "Esquema", um Protocolo como HTTP, HTTPS, FTP.
Queria saber como posso fazer este Protocolo para abrir um programa, igual o Torrent, com o Protocolo Magnet.

Alem disso, queria saber se possível criar este protocolo via java.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/389204/how-do-i-create-my-own-url-protocol-e-g-so

Comment: Ja tentei entender isso mas nao consigo.

Comment: É uma pena que tenham fechado é uma dúvida "válida" e com pouquíssimas repostas praticas na web. Além do que o link para uma resposta explanada no **SOen** já tem mais de 8 anos e não é viável nos sistemas Windows atuais.

Comment: Uma resposta mais pratica aqui da comunidade: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/112202/registrar-um-protocolo-customizado-no-windows