# Registrar um protocolo customizado no Windows

Tags: vb.net

Não sei se estou perguntando de forma correta, mas não sei por onde começar a pesquisar. Gostaria de registrar um protocolo customizado no windows igual algumas aplicações fazem. Exemplo:

- Spotify -> spotify:
- Torrent -> magnet:
- email -> mailto:

Por onde começo a minha pesquisa? Imagino que seja necessário escrever no registro do windows mas não sei como pesquisar sobre esse caso especifico.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esses protocolos são chamados de [Esquemas de URI](https://www.iana.org/assignments/uri-schemes/uri-schemes.xhtml). Você pode criar protocolos para seu projeto usando esquemas de URI no registro do Windows, navegando no caminho:

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT/
   seu_protocolo_aqui/
       (Default)              = "URL:nome do protocolo"
       URL Protocol           = ""
       DefaultIcon
           (Default)          = "aplicativo.exe,1"
       shell
           open
               command
                    (Default) = "C:\Users\Kaizonaro\Desktop\aplicativo.exe" "%1"
```

Seja onde `seu_protocolo_aqui` o protocolo que você quer associar nas URIS (como por exemplo `mailto:`, `blablabla:` sem o `:`), e no "nome do protocolo" um nome qualquer para o Windows reconhecer no seu aplicativo.

Vamos colocar como no `seu_protocolo_aqui` para `foobar`, chamaríamos o seu aplicativo usando os argumentos assim:

`foobar:ola%20mundo` *//seja no `%20` um caractere de espaço*

Para obter o que foi chamado no argumento `ola%20mundo` basta usar a função [`Command()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.interaction.command%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Se quiser mais informações de como usar esquemas de URI no Windows com .NET Framework, de uma olhada [nesse link aqui](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767914%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).